# Can you take frozen meat from Thailand when going through a land border?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, borders, thailand

Will I have any legal problems if I buy a lot of frozen meat in Macro in Thailand, and keep it in a portable freezer powered from the car battery, and want to cross borders to neighboring countries (Cambodia, Laos, Vietnam, Malaysia, Singapore, Indonesia) with the car?

To which of these countries I will be allowed to drive with my meat and to which not (in case it gets checked)? And will I be allowed to cross the border back to Thailand with it?

This will be unopened, sealed, packages New-Zealand sourced lamb if that helps. This will be for personal consumption only, but I might want to take 10 kg for example, as I can eat half a kilo a day, and might be 3 weeks away from a Macro.

Answer (score 5):

I can only tell you about Laos: not a problem here. People in Vientiane go shopping for food in Thailand all the time, and add far as I know fresh unpackaged meat could be a problem (although nobody had ever even asked us to open the trunk at the border) but hygienically packed it's definitely fine.
No idea about the neighbors though, sorry.